# understanding self::DISPLAY_TYPE_NEW_PRODUCTS

Tags: magento-1.9

I am learning magento and I have some doubts about how it works, could someone help me with it or can suggest some tutorial from where I can learn more about magento. In

```
/app/design/frontend/../../template/catalog/product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml
```

file there is a piece of code

```
$this->getProductCollection()
```

I know this function can be found in

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/Widget/New.php
```

But there is no such function, I also looked in the parent class and there also I could not find this function.

I found another function in

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/Widget/New.php
```

Below is the function

```
protected function _getProductCollection()
{
    switch ($this->getDisplayType()) {
        case self::DISPLAY_TYPE_NEW_PRODUCTS:
            $collection = parent::_getProductCollection();
            break;
        default:
            $collection = $this->_getRecentlyAddedProductsCollection();
            break;
    }
    return $collection;
}
```

and I know this function is called but my question is why and how? These two have different names then how they can be same. Do it means that "_" is only used if a function is protected and it does not have to do anything with the function name.

And also when I echoed

```
$this->getDisplayType()
```

then I got 'new_products' but if you see in this function then magento is using self::DISPLAY_TYPE_NEW_PRODUCTS in case then how these two cases or strings are similar.

Also please explain this line

```
parent::_getProductCollection()
```

do it means call _getProductCollection() from parent class and if yes then where this is specified in magento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) Regarding: $this->getProductCollection() method:**

Check file:

> /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/Widget/New.php

This is having **_beforeToHtml()** method at line no.127(Line number can be different for different version of Magento).

```
/**
 * Prepare collection with new products
 *
 * @return Mage_Core_Block_Abstract
 */
protected function _beforeToHtml()
{
    $this->setProductCollection($this->_getProductCollection());
    return parent::_beforeToHtml();
}
```

Above method sets product collection before html render.

**Note:**
**getProductCollection()** and **_getProductCollection()** are not same. Both are completely different method.

**2) $this->getDisplayType()**

Any constant variable can be defined using **const** statement.

```
const DISPLAY_TYPE_NEW_PRODUCTS = 'new_products';
```

and that variable can be used as:

```
self::DISPLAY_TYPE_NEW_PRODUCTS;
```

So, **self::DISPLAY_TYPE_NEW_PRODUCTS** will return **new_products**.